# Why does curl fail while using this export?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm doing some stuff with Facebooks FQL at the moment, and I'm using `curl` on the command line to test some of the responses of it. I'm also using `export` to keep the params seperated for easy editing. But I'm doing something wrong, and I can't see what.

This produces a perfectly fine result (even with the export):

```
export FB_TOKEN="the_access_token"
curl -F access_token=$FB_TOKEN -F query="SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE uid=12345678910123" https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query
```

But this does mess up:

```
export FB_TOKEN="the_access_token"
export FB_QUERY="SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE uid=12345678910123"
curl -F access_token=$FB_TOKEN -F query=$FB_QUERY https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query
```

and produces the following output:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'first_name'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'FROM'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'user'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'WHERE'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'uid=100001273321556'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
(...further response that the request was invalid here...)
```

I don't see anything I forgot to escape. Why does `curl` insist on interpreting these as hosts?

*Used software versions:

curl 7.21.3; bash 4.2.8(1)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FB_QUERY` must be quoted:

```
curl -F access_token=$FB_TOKEN -F query="$FB_QUERY" https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query
```

Comment: Damn. I thank you for my facepalm of the day. =)